Let $\phi : G \rightarrow G'$ be an isomorphism. Prove that if H is a normal subgroup of G, then $\phi(H)$ is a normal subgroup of G'.
Here was attempt at a solution: solution. This is the feedback I received :

You have not used anywhere the fact that phi is an isomorphism, but this is false when phi is only a homomorphism.  The error is in your claim about how to show $\phi(H)$ is normal in $\overline G$: you need that for any $\bar g\in \overline G$ that $\bar g\phi(H)\bar g^{-1}$ is $\phi(H)$.

Can anyone help me understand how to fix my solution? I can't figure out why I have to use the fact that its an isomorphism and why I wouldn't work if its a homormorphism.


Please stop posting with links to pictures. Include all the relevant information on your post, and use MathJax to typeset math. 2. Please tag your questions correctly; both your most recent questions are about group theory, but you only tag them "abstract algebra".


Your solution looks mostly fine, but with a small logical error (or maybe not enough detail).
You show that for every $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, $\phi(g)\phi(h)\phi(g)^{-1} \in \phi(H).$
What you really need to show is that for every $\overline{g} \in \overline{G}$ and $\overline{h} \in \phi(H)$, $\overline{g}\overline{h}(\overline{g})^{-1} \in \phi(H)$. These are two similar (but different) statements. But when $\phi$ is an isomorphism, they're actually equivalent!
The idea is to take $\overline{g} \in \overline{G}$ and $\overline{h} \in \phi(H)$. Then, using the surjectivity of $\phi$, you can find $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ such that $\phi(g) = \overline{g}$ and $\phi(h) = \overline{h}.$
From here, the argument is pretty much identical to your argument. The general gist is to pass from $\phi(H)$ to $H$ using the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.
EDIT for clarification: $\phi$ is surjective because $\phi$ is an isomorphism, and hence a bijection, and hence a surjection.

Thank you for help I see the difference now!

I will only briefly go into your proof. You claimed that you only have to show that \begin{equation}\Phi(g) \Phi(H) \Phi(g)^{-1} \subset H^\prime \enspace \forall g \in G. \quad (1)\end{equation} However, you must show that $$g_* \Phi(H) g_*^{-1} \subset H^\prime \enspace \forall g_* \in G^\prime. \enspace (2)$$ You can see that there is a subtle difference. Now your proof is still sufficient. Why? Because $\Phi$ is an isomorphism, therefore $\Phi$ is bijective. Now you can simply set $g = \Phi^{-1}(g_*)$ for any $g_*$ in (1) and you get (2).

Thank you for the help!
